# why it cant read bmp file.?

Tags: java, image-processing

Actually this is the code for getting the dpi of an image.and it does but only for smaller size jpeg files not for the bmp file.i want to get bmp file dpi.

i have also tried bufferedimage for read the file but it does not work.

```
 ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File("MAR.BMP"));
    Iterator it = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
    if (!it.hasNext())
    {
        System.err.println("No reader for this format");

    }
    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) it.next();
    reader.setInput(iis);

    IIOMetadata meta = reader.getImageMetadata(0);
    IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode) meta.getAsTree("javax_imageio_1.0");
    NodeList nodes = root.getElementsByTagName("HorizontalPixelSize");
    if (nodes.getLength() >0)
    {
        IIOMetadataNode dpcWidth = (IIOMetadataNode) nodes.item(0);
        NamedNodeMap nnm = dpcWidth.getAttributes();
        Node item = nnm.item(0);
        int xDPI = Math.round(25.4f / Float.parseFloat(item.getNodeValue()));
        System.out.println("xDPI: " + xDPI);
    }
    else

        System.out.println("xDPI: -");

    if (nodes.getLength() >0)
    {
        nodes = root.getElementsByTagName("VerticalPixelSize");
        IIOMetadataNode dpcHeight = (IIOMetadataNode) nodes.item(0);
        NamedNodeMap nnm = dpcHeight.getAttributes();
        Node item = nnm.item(0);
        int yDPI = Math.round(25.4f / Float.parseFloat(item.getNodeValue()));
        System.out.println("yDPI: " + yDPI);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("yDPI: -");

    }
    }
```

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: i am using jdk 8.1.

Comment: I think there's a bug in `BMPMetadata` that incorrectly sets `HorizontalPhysicalPixelSpacing` and `VerticalPhysicalPixelSpacing` instead of `HorizontalPixelSize` and `VerticalPixelSize`. But this only happens if the data (x/y pixels per meter) is present in the BMP (which is often not the case). If absent, you should just assume some default (ie. 72 DPI)  I guess.